# Adjacency list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I am looking for a concise and precise adjacency list representation of a graph in C++. My nodes are just node ids. Here is how I did it. Just want to know what experts think about it. Is there a better way?

This is the class implementation (nothing fancy, right now don't care about public/private methods)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class adjList {
public:
    int head;
    vector<int> listOfNodes;
    void print();
};

void adjList :: print() {
    for (int i=0; i<listOfNodes.size(); ++i) {
        cout << head << "-->" << listOfNodes.at(i) << endl;
    }
}

class graph {
public:
    vector<adjList> list;
    void print();
};

void graph :: print() {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i) {
        list.at(i).print();
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

My main function parses an input file line by line. Where each line is interpreted as following:

```
<source_node> <node1_connected_to_source_node> <node2_connected_to_source_node <node3_connected_to_source_node> <...>
```

Here is the main:

```
int main()
    {
        fstream file("graph.txt", ios::in);
        string line;
        graph g;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            int source;
            stringstream str(line);
            str >> source;
            int node2;
            adjList l;
            l.head = source;
            while (str >> node2) {
                l.listOfNodes.push_back(node2);
            }
            g.list.push_back(l);
        }
        file.close();
        g.print();
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

I know I should add addEdge() function inside adjList class instead of directly modifying its variable from main() however, right now I just wonder about the best structure.

**EDIT:**
There is one shortcoming in my approach. For a complicated graph with large number of nodes, node will indeed be a struct/class and in that case I will be duplicating values by storing the whole object. In that case I think I should use pointers. For example for an undirected graph, I will be storing copies of node objects in the adjList (connection between node 1 and 2 means 1's adjacency list will have 2 and vice versa). I can avoid that by storing pointers of node objects in the adjList instead of the whole object. Check the dfs implementation which get benefited by this approach. There I need to insure that each node gets visited only once. Having multiple copies of the same node will make my life harder. no?

In this case my class definitions will change like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    node() {}
    node(int id, bool _dirty): node_id(id), dirty(_dirty) {}
    int node_id;
    bool dirty;
};

class adjList {
public:
    node *head;
    vector<node*> listOfNodes;
    void print();
    ~adjList() { delete head;}
};

void adjList :: print() {
    for (int i=0; i<listOfNodes.size(); ++i) {
        cout << head->node_id << "-->" << listOfNodes.at(i)->node_id << endl;
    }
}

class graph {
public:
    vector<adjList> list;
    void print();
    void dfs(node *startNode);
};

void graph::dfs(node *startNode) {
    startNode->dirty = true;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i) {
        node *stNode = list.at(i).head;
        if (stNode->node_id != startNode->node_id) { continue;}
        for (int j=0; j<list.at(i).listOfNodes.size(); ++j) {
            if (!list.at(i).listOfNodes.at(j)->dirty) {
                dfs(list.at(i).listOfNodes.at(j));
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Node: "<<startNode->node_id << endl;
}

void graph :: print() {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i) {
        list.at(i).print();
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is how I implemented main() function. I am using a map<> to avoid duplication of objects. Creating a new object only when its not defined earlier. Checking existence of an object by its id.

```
int main()
{
    fstream file("graph.txt", ios::in);
    string line;
    graph g;
    node *startNode;
    map<int, node*> nodeMap;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        int source;
        stringstream str(line);
        str >> source;
        int node2;
        node *sourceNode;
        // Create new node only if a node does not already exist
        if (nodeMap.find(source) == nodeMap.end()) {
                sourceNode = new node(source, false);
                nodeMap[source] = sourceNode;
        } else {
                sourceNode = nodeMap[source];
        }
        adjList l;
        l.head = sourceNode;
        nodeMap[source] = sourceNode;
        while (str >> node2) {
            // Create new node only if a node does not already exist
            node *secNode;
            if (nodeMap.find(node2) == nodeMap.end()) {
                secNode = new node(node2, false);
                nodeMap[node2] = secNode;
            } else {
                secNode = nodeMap[node2];
            }
            l.listOfNodes.push_back(secNode);
        }
        g.list.push_back(l);
        startNode = sourceNode;
    }
    file.close();
    g.print();
    g.dfs(startNode);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**
After *Ulrich Eckhardt* suggestion to put adjacency list in node class, here is what I think is a better data structure to store a graph and perform dfs(), dijkstra() kind of operations. Please note that adjacency list is merged in node class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    node() {
    }
    node(int id, bool _dirty): node_id(id), dirty(_dirty) {
        //cout << "In overloaded const\n";
    }
    int node_id;
    bool dirty;
    vector<node*> listOfNodes;
};

class graph {
public:
    vector<node*> myGraph;
    void dfs(node* startNode);
};

void graph::dfs(node* startNode) {
    startNode->dirty = true;
    for (int j=0; j<startNode->listOfNodes.size(); ++j) {
            if (!startNode->listOfNodes.at(j)->dirty) {
                dfs(startNode->listOfNodes.at(j));
            }
        }

    cout << "Node: "<<startNode->node_id << endl;
}
```

Can we do better than this?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what you need to do with this graph, but what you have seems pretty reasonable and simple.

Comment: true...but there is one problem though...for an undirected graph, I will be storing copies of node objects in the adjList (connection between node 1 and 2 means 1's adjacency list will have 2 and vice versa). I can avoid that by storing pointers of node objects in the adjList instead of the whole object. But this leads to another discussion of heap vs stack. Hence want to know what people generally use.

Comment: Isn't `adjList` only storing indices of nodes? Don't you need to define a node class somewhere btw?

Comment: yes... after defining node class...thanks! I missed that...

Comment: I think that your approach works, but that it is horribly inefficient. In `dfs()`, you are doing a linear scan over the vector of adjacency lists to find the one for the current node, which is O(nodes). You are doing that for every node, making it O(nodes * nodes). The problem is your data structure, which should include the adjacency list in the node: `struct node{ vector<node*> adjacency_list; };` Then, your graph becomes a simple `map<int, node> nodes;`. Traversing the adjacent nodes is then a simple loop over `adjacency_list`, without any additional cost.

Comment: It just occurred to me that using the `map<int, node>` even eliminates the hack with the reinterpret_cast below and it isn't slower, so that's the way to go. And don't worry about the redundant storage of the edges in an undirected graph. If you have that many edges, you should consider a compressed adjacency matrix anyway, but that then also changes the complexity of iterating over all edges of a node. Take the easy road until you see a real need to go a different way.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, dfs() is horrible slow because of my inefficient implementation. Your solution is a very good observation. Thanks! Can you edit your answer to include this comment as well? I can then mark it as an accepted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be improved, but in general your approach is reasonable. Notes:

- You are using `int` as index into a container, which will give you warning from some compilers, because the size of a container could exceed the size representable as `int`. Instead, use `size_t`.
- Rewrite your `for (int i=0; i<list.size(); ++i)` to `for(size_t i=0, size=list.size(); i!=size; ++i)`. Using `!=` instead of `<` will work with iterators. Reading and storing the size once makes it easier to debug and possibly even more efficient.
- Inside the loop to print, you have `list.at(i).print();`. The `list.at(i)` will verify the index is valid and raise an exception when not. In this very simple case, I am sure that the index is valid, so using `list[i]` instead is faster. Also, it implicitly documents that the index is valid and not that you expect it to be invalid.
- The `print()` functions should be constant.
- I don't understand what the `int head` is. Is this some kind of ID for the node? And isn't the ID simply the index inside `graph::list`? If it is the index, you could compute that on demand using the address of the element minus the address of the first element, so there's no need to store it redundantly. Also, consider validating that index when reading, so you don't have any edges going to a vertex that doesn't exist.
- If you don't care about encapsulation on a node-level (which is reasonable!), you could also make this a struct, which saves some typing.
- Storing pointers instead of indices is tricky but could improve speed. The problem is that for reading, you might need a pointer to a vertex that doesn't exist yet. There is a hack that allows doing that without using additional storage, it requires first storing the indices in the pointer values (using reinterpret_cast) and after reading, making a second pass on the data where you adjust these values to the actual addresses. Of course, you can also use the second pass to validate that you don't have any edges going to vertices that don't exist at all (which is a place where the `at(i)` function becomes useful) so this second pass to verify some guarantees is a good thing anyway.

On explicit request, here's an example for how to store an index in a pointer:

```
// read file
for(...) {
    size_t id = read_id_from_file();
    node* node_ptr = reinterpret_cast<node*>(id);
    adjacency_list.push_back(node_ptr);
}

/* Note that at this point, you do have node* that don't contain
valid addresses but just the IDs of the nodes they should finally
point to, so you must not use these pointers! */

// make another pass over all nodes after reading the file
for(size_t i=0, size=adjacency_list.size(); i!=size; ++i) {
    // read ID from adjacency list
    node* node_ptr = adjacency_list[i];
    size_t id = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(node_ptr);
    // convert ID to actual address
    node_ptr = lookup_node_by_id(id);
    if(!node_ptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("unknown node ID in adjacency list");
    // store actual node address in adjacency list
    adjacency_list[i] = node_ptr;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this works in general, though I'm not 100% sure if this is guaranteed to work, which was why I'm reluctant to post this here. However, I hope this also makes clear why I'm asking what exactly "head" is. If it is really just the index in a container, there is little need for it, neither inside the file nor in memory. If it is some kind of name or identifier for a node that you retrieved from a file, then you absolutely need it, but then you can't use it as index, the values there could as well start their IDs with 1 or 1000, which you should catch and handle without crashing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Regarding your 4th point, head stores the source node id. Now I see its redundant as well. Head node could well be the first node in adjList. I did not understand your last point fully. May be if you have time you can give a short example. For a complicated graphs with large number of nodes, node will indeed be a struct/class and in that case I will be duplicating values by storing the whole object. In that case I think I should use pointers. See the edit to my question.